# How does new Task in ASP.NET Core utilize dependency injection?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, task

I'm using ASP.NET CORE 2.0.5 runtime for my WEBAPI project. In my implementation when a request comes in a new Task is started to do some heavy lifting work and eventually makes a request to a webapi else where. In the mean time I'm returning a success response back to my caller.

The problem is that since the heavy lifting work takes longer time to process, I cannot utilize all the DI services I set up in the Startup class, because the original request has already been returned and all the DI services are disposed.

Is there a way to pass my IServiceCollection to the new Task or is there a better approach to this?

UPDATE:

It turned out not every DI service was disposed. It was only this one:

```
services.AddTransient<HttpMessageHandler, HttpClientHandler>();
```

This line is to enable unit test. Without it my webapi runs fine but my unit test breaks...

Comment: Do read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.1) on docs. The part you want is setting up a Scope, but you should know about the rest too.

Comment: Thanks @HenkHolterman. Sorry it's been a long time but you WERE pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

Asp.Net Core DI provides 3 options for service lifetime:

- **Transient** - Transient lifetime services are created each time they're requested. They're disposed along with the service which uses it.
- **Scoped** - Scoped lifetime services are created once per request. They're disposed along with the scope.
- **Singleton** - Singleton lifetime services are created the first time they're requested. They live while the app is alive.

So, you cannot pass to the background task transient or scoped service since it will be disposed when main thread stops. But there is `IServiceScopeFactory` which can create a scope for you inside the background task execution, where you can safely resolve your dependency, e.g.:

```
private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

public Service(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
{
    _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
}

public void RunBackgroundTask()
{    
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(state => { 
        using (scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var dependencyService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SecondService));
            // do your work here
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the dependencies are disposed per each request a better approach would be to use a background task for the "heavy lifting" part.

When you receive the request, you could persist the data somehow (one approach would be to use a database) and after that return the response to the caller.
You can then use a background task independently. The background task would check periodically if there are any requests stored and if yes, it can do the "heavy lifting" work, send the request and clean up the stored request.